# Trouble comparing double values for Hashmap and Edittext

Tags: java, android, hashmap, double

I getting a problem while trying to compare two double values (one value from `hashmap` and other from `Edittext`). There is no error but at the same time result is wrong.

Declared 3 variables:

```
    double a,b,c; 
a=Double.parseDouble(Value1.getText().toString());
b=Double.parseDouble(Value2.getText().toString());
c=Double.parseDouble(Value3.getText().toString());
```

Now declared `Hashmap`, Since hashmap doesn't take primitive types hence declared as below.

```
HashMap<String, Double> StoreDatabasevalues =new HashMap<String, Double>();
StoreDatabasevalues.put("a",a1); //a1,a2,a3 are from database
StoreDatabasevalues.put("b",a2);
StoreDatabasevalues.put("c",a3);
```

Attempt 1:

```
if(a==StoreDatabasevalues.get("a") || b==StoreDatabasevalues.get("b") || c==StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")){
//mycode here
}
else if (a!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("a") || b!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("b") || c!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")){
//mycode here
}
```

This resulted in failure as though values are different control is not going to `else if` part.

Attempt 2: Since I am not using a primitive type in `HashMap` tried below approach.

```
if(StoreDatabasevalues.get("a").equals(a) || StoreDatabasevalues.get("b").equals(b) || StoreDatabasevalues.get("c").equals(c)){
    //mycode here
    }
    else if (!StoreDatabasevalues.get("a").equals(a) || !StoreDatabasevalues.get("b").equals(b) || !StoreDatabasevalues.get("c").equals(c)){
    //mycode here
    }
```

This attempt was also a failure because I gave a different values but control is not going to `else if` part.

Comment: what are a1,a2 and a3 ?

Comment: @LMK those are variable sthat store the values retrived from database

Comment: Please explain how a, b, and c are assigned their values, adding the code.

Comment: @laune Please find my edit on how I declare vlaues. thanks

Comment: StoreDatabasevalues.get("a") is a String, try Double.parseDouble(StoreDatabasevalues.get("a"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(a==StoreDatabasevalues.get("a") ||
   b==StoreDatabasevalues.get("b") ||
   c==StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")){
    //mycode 1 here
}
else if (a!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("a") ||
         b!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("b") ||             
         c!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")){
   //mycode 2 here
}
```

Quote: "This resulted in failure as though values are different control is not going to else if part."

Quite so: if *at least one* of the three values a, b, c matches, control will reache "mycode 1".

Use this:

```
if(a==StoreDatabasevalues.get("a") &&
   b==StoreDatabasevalues.get("b") &&
   c==StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")){
    //mycode 1 here - all three values are the same.
}
else /*** if (a!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("a") ||
              b!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("b") ||             
             c!=StoreDatabasevalues.get("c"))   ***/ {
   //mycode 2 here
}
```

The seocnd condition is now redundant, being the negation of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I think you spotted the problem thats fine with `if` part your answer works.. but when it comes to `else if` part if any of the value is not equal (`suppose b value is not equal and remianing two are equal`) then I need the control to go to `my code 2` what should be the logic here? thanks again

Comment: Well, you don't need to change that part - in fact the second if is redundant, it's now the negation of the changed first condition. For clarity, I'Ve edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input I was able to solve my issue.. I am wondering how I have missed that logic.. anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

As i know, you can not compare two float, doouble values. You can compare them just with 0. Try this method. This method returns the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2.

```
     // compares the two specified double values
     double d1 = 15.45;
     double d2 = 11.50;
     int retval = Double.compare(d1, d2);

     if(retval > 0) {
        System.out.println("d1 is greater than d2");
     }
     else if(retval < 0) {
        System.out.println("d1 is less than d2");
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("d1 is equal to d2");
     }
```

Or try something like this for equal compare:

```
if(a-StoreDatabasevalues.get("a")<0.00001 || b-StoreDatabasevalues.get("b")<0.00001 || c-StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")<0.00001){
//do something
}
else if(Math.abs(a-StoreDatabasevalues.get("a"))>0.00001 || Math.abs(b-StoreDatabasevalues.get("b"))>0.00001 || Math.abs(c-StoreDatabasevalues.get("c"))>0.00001){
//do something
}
```

Or Try to make the string to double:

```
if(Double.parseDouble(StoreDatabasevalues.get("a")).equals(a) || Double.parseDouble(StoreDatabasevalues.get("b")).equals(b) || Double.parseDouble(StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")).equals(c)){
    //mycode here
    }
    else if (!Double.parseDouble(StoreDatabasevalues.get("a")).equals(a) || !Double.parseDouble(StoreDatabasevalues.get("b")).equals(b) || !Double.parseDouble(StoreDatabasevalues.get("c")).equals(c)){
    //mycode here
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I need to compare approximately 20 values in `if` condition...... is there any simple way

Comment: I edited my answer with subtraction option, now you can compare more values. Add some logic or adjust it with your needs. You can not say `double1 == double2`, you have to make `double1-double2<0.00001` then you can say it is "equal" :)

Comment: Of course you can compare two double values provided they have been produced in exactly the same way *excluding* any arithmetic operation, i.e., just by conversion from (the same) string, or by casting an integer, or similar transformation.

Comment: @laune why would you need to compare the same with the same?

Comment: @Martynas Thanks for your edit... this is fine for equal case then how about not equal case? Can you please explain that aswell

Comment: If you know that all of your double values have a "safe" (as explained in my previous comment) past, you can compare them using ==, !=,... and expect to get correct results.

Comment: in your place i would consider what is not equal. If >0.00001 is fine for you then just copy/paste and change Less `<` to more `>` then make `Math.abs(a-StoreDatabasevalues.get("a"))>0.00001` this `Math.abs` is to make it always possitive in that case when `a<StoreDatabasevalues.get("a")`

Comment: @Martynas Don't *ever* use a literal like `0.00001` to test for two doubles being "almost equal". Elementary numerical mathematics teaches you to distinguish between *absolute* and *relative* error. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error

Comment: @laune thats why i wrote **If >0.00001 is fine for you**

Comment: @Martynas OK, but I've learned to add an explanation to such advice. But it seems we're on to an entirely different track anyway.

Comment: @Siva look my last edit. I noticed that you try to compare string with double? `Double.parseDouble(string)` converst string to double.

Comment: @Martynas Thanks for taking your time in helping me... but laune advice solved my issue... you certainly helped by showing a different way to compare the double which I am unaware of.. Thank you very much...

Comment: No problem Siva, i am not expert too, but try to help and also improve my knowledge :)) Cheers to you and @laune :)